# creating categories programmatically

Tags: categories, taxonomy

I'm creating a batch uploader and it would be good if I could also add categories with parent categories to my posts.

I have the following code:

```
        $my_cat = array(
        'cat_name' => $cat_name,
        'category_description' => $cat_desc,
        'category_nicename' => $cat_slug,
        'category_parent' => $cat_parent);

if(function_exists('wp_insert_category')){
    $my_cat_id = wp_insert_category($my_cat);

}elseif(function_exists('wp_create_category')){
    $my_cat_id = wp_create_category($cat_name,$cat_parent);

}elseif(function_exists('wp_insert_term')){

    $parent_term = term_exists( $cat_name, $cat_parent );
    $parent_term_id = $parent_term['term_id'];
    $var = wp_insert_term($cat_name,$cat_parent);

    if ( is_wp_error($var) ){
    echo $var->get_error_message();
    echo " Category ";var_dump($cat_name);echo" failed to be created ";
    }
```

both $cat_name and $cat_parent are always valid with some value and $cat_parent exists always prior to creating $cat_name.

but always all I get is

> Invalid taxonomy

which means that the last elseif runs.

i'm running this code from the theme's functions.php file

SO I have 2 questions:

first: why wont neither of the first two if cases run? (If i remove the if exists check, it reports that the function does not exist)

second: why the 3rd wont run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_insert_category` and `wp_create_category` are both in wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php. They're not general use functions and can't be used *just anywhere*. `wp_insert_term` is, but you're using it incorrectly. See [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) for details on proper usage, but in short, here's a cheat sheet:

```
wp_insert_term( $term, $taxonomy, $args = array() );
...
$defaults = array( 'alias_of' => '', 'description' => '', 'parent' => 0, 'slug' => '');
```

I believe what you want to change your code to say is,

```
$var = wp_insert_term( $cat_name, 'category', array( 'parent' => $parent_term_id ) );
```

Comment: Absolutely, happy to help!